# Python Telegram Bot ensure state changes in Job callback

Tags: python, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot, job-queue

I've scheduled a Job which sends users a message and expects a response. How can I ensure the conversation state changes in the callback? The following does not seem to work.

```
def job_callback_function(context: CallbackContext):
    send_message("What is your favorite color?", chat_id)
    return new_state
```

Comment: Is the job scheduled while the conversation is already ongoing or do you want the conversation to start with the users response to that message? Please have a look at [this guide](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Ask-right) on how to ask good questions on PTB.